# Send normal Siri commands through coding

Tags: iphone

I am completely new to this but here goes anyway. I've been reading that Siri has no access via API. My question might be a tad different.

What I would Like to do is send Siri this message 
What is the weather like today

That's it, nothing new. I'm not trying to make Siri do something  it doesn't already do. I'm just trying to send that message in my own code rather than hitting the button and saying it.

Any thoughts???
Thanks !!!

Comment: And in order to do that, you need an API for Siri. See the problem?

Comment: It seems people are somehow doing it though.

Comment: http://www.theiphonespot.net/create-your-own-custom-commands-for-assistantextentions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that. Apple has not yet provided any public APIs to developers for Siri programming. Also the link that you provide in one of your comments, it is for jailbroken devices. They must have used the private APIs.